# Issue with getting keyCode of Tab key in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript

I have one issue regarding to getting KeyCode of Tab Key in Chrome , however its working fine in Mozila.

HTML:

```
<h3>Press Tab key</h3>
<input type="text" onkeyup=" return actionPerform(event)"/>
```

Script:

```
function actionPerform(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode === 9) {
        console.log(charCode);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here is the Fiddle [CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/7952/)

What do you suggest? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your issue? What is not working? Some of your readers will not be using Chrome, so they can't see the error for themselves when they run your code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the HTML:

```
<h3>Press Tab key</h3>
<input type="text" onkeydown="return blockTab(event);" onkeyup=" return actionPerform(event);"/>
```

here is the JS:

```
function actionPerform(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode === 9) {
        console.log(charCode);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function blockTab(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode === 9) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Yaa Ashutosh its working with keydown i know that but as per requirement i can not use keydown here

Comment: @Mahesh I have updated the answer. Please have a look.